# why can't i save data inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a dictionary called users and it saves the user data that he inputs in a textinput in kivy ...however it works fine but when i rerun the program the info is all gone it is not saved and i need to add the user again ..also it's an atm system so i edit in the values of that dictionary which means i can't save it to a file.

```
    class Data:
        users = {}
        def add_user(self, email, 
password,name,lastname,country,num,day,month,year,gender,balance,created):
            if email not in self.users:
                self.users[email] = 

[password,name,lastname,country,num,day,month,year,gender,balance,created]

                return 1
            else:
                print("Email exists!")
                return -1
        def get_user(self, email):
            if email in self.users:
                return self.users[email]
            else:
                return -1
        def validate(self, email, password):
            if self.get_user(email) != -1:
                return self.users[email][0] == password
            else:
                return False


    class Depositpage(Screen,Widget,Data):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Depositpage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            btn1 = Button(text='Add',size_hint=(0.08,0.06),pos_hint= 
 {'x':0.903,'top':0.599},color=(0,0,0,1),background_color=(0,0,0,0))
        btn1.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.add())
        self.txt1= TextInput(multiline=False,size_hint=(0.45,0.13),pos_hint= 
{'x':0.27,'top':0.475},font_size=43)
        #self.ballabel = Label(text="text",font_size=20,pos_hint= 
{'x':-0.04,'top':1.27},color=(0,0,0,1))
        self.add_widget(self.txt1)
        self.add_widget(btn1)
        #self.add_widget(self.ballabel)
    def add(self):
        result = int(self.users['mo@gmail.com'][9]) + int(self.txt1.text)
        self.users['mo@gmail.com'][9] = result
        print(f"add {self.users['mo@gmail.com'][9]}")
        print(self.users['mo@gmail.com'][9])
```

Comment: A dictionary is not a way to store data *persistently*. You need to use a database, pickle the data, or some other form of serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is not designed to store data persistently.

Though you can dump it to a JSON file, and then load it from there where you need it?

```
import json

with open('my_dict.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_dict, f)

# elsewhere...

with open('my_dict.json') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)
```

Loading from JSON is fairly efficient.

Another option would be to use pickle and marshal modules, but unlike JSON, the files it generates aren't human-readable, turns many Python data types into a stream of bytes and then recreate the objects from the bytes.

Data persistence in Python: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html

Comment: You can then use pickle. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works. See how you can adopt it to your code.

```
import json

data = {'x':7}

# save the dict to disk
with open('data.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
# read the json into a dict
with open('data.json','r') as f:
    data_from_disk = json.loads(f.read())

print('data_from_disk: ' + str(data_from_disk))
```

output

```
data_from_disk: {'x': 7}
```